# Polling System Memory

Tags: c#, memory

I'm trying to query the RAM on the machine my application is running on. I tried a number of different methods of getting this info and have gotten some weird results. Below you'll see the different methods I've tried out with the result commented above the `MessageBox.Show` call.

The third is returning KB and I notice that this is installed Memory Vs the first two methods which are getting Physical Memory. Is this correct and accounting for the differing result?

I have checked a number of different methods of polling the RAM on my system; msinfo32.exe, dxdiag, CPU-Z, Task Manager, Control Panel\System. All of which list 8GB of memory except for dxdiag which more specifically says 8192MB RAM.

My query is this. How do I corroborate the results of any/all of these methods? As the numbers do not match I cannot confirm the third method to be more accurate than the first two. I'm aware that I may be doing something silly like converting incorrectly but double checking myself in Google's "bytes/kb to gb" converter has assuaged that.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

    ...
    ulong installedMemory = 0;
    MEMORYSTATUSEX memStatus = new MEMORYSTATUSEX();
    if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(memStatus))
    {
        installedMemory = memStatus.ullTotalPhys;
    }

    //8542273536
    MessageBox.Show(installedMemory.ToString());
    //8542273536
    MessageBox.Show(GetTotalMemoryInBytes().ToString());
    GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long memKb);
    //8388608
    MessageBox.Show(memKb.ToString());
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private class MEMORYSTATUSEX
{
    public uint dwLength;
    public uint dwMemoryLoad;
    public ulong ullTotalPhys;
    public ulong ullAvailPhys;
    public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
    public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
    public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
    public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
    public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
    public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
    {
        this.dwLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(this);
    }
}

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out] MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);
static ulong GetTotalMemoryInBytes()
{
    return new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
}
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long TotalMemoryInKilobytes);
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I'm logging processing time and memory (among other info) for each machine my app is run on, to a central database so that I can cross check this info and see how differing machine specs affect processing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` excludes the small amount of memory that's not available because it's mapped to hardware (like an integrated graphics controller, and DMA ranges). `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` just gives the size of all the RAM installed regardless of its availability to the OS, to prevent angry customers from returning the computer because they're not getting all their advertised bytes. But don't take my word for it, believe the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc300158):

> The `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` function retrieves the amount
>   of physically installed RAM from the computer's SMBIOS firmware
>   tables. This can differ from the amount reported by the
>   `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function, which sets the `ullTotalPhys` member of
>   the `MEMORYSTATUSEX` structure to the amount of physical memory that is
>   available for the operating system to use. The amount of memory
>   available to the operating system can be less than the amount of
>   memory physically installed in the computer because the BIOS and some
>   drivers may reserve memory as I/O regions for memory-mapped devices,
>   making the memory unavailable to the operating system and
>   applications.

In other words, both results are correct: you have 8 GiB total physical RAM installed, of which 8542273536 bytes are actually available to Windows for allocation purposes.

Comment: Ok so it was the numbers that were throwing me off. Is the following correct given my numbers above? 8388608 KiB = 8 GiB => Physical Memory. 8542273536 B = 7.955 GiB => Accessible Memory.

Comment: @windowskm: yes. Note that you can use PowerShell to calculate these things very quickly: it has built in `kb`, `mb`, `gb` suffixes, so that (for example) `8388608kb / 1gb` is `8`, and `8542273536 / 1gb` is `7.95561218261719`.

Comment: Can we get this using PowerShell like I am trying `$refAsm = if( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -le 5 ) { 
            @{ ReferencedAssemblies = 'System.Numerics' } 
        } else { @{} }

Add-Type @refAsm -TypeDefinition @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory(out long TotalMemoryInKilobytes);
'@` but getting error `Expected class, delegate, enum, 
interface, or struct`

Comment: @NaveenKumar: that sounds like a new question. Be sure to tag it `powershell`.